# AS3 - Slow Render Speeds

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, timer

I've written a basic velocity-based animation engine which iterates over a list of custom Shape objects which hold direction and velocity.  When animating more than 500 objects, my application sees significant slowdown, but the actual time it takes to change the positions of the objects is very low.

**Results are roughly as follows:**

```
100 objects - <1ms modification time, 60 FPS
500 objects - 2ms modification time, 40 FPS
1000 objects - 4ms modification time, 10 FPS
```

I am currently using Timer-based animation, and my timer is set to 15ms intervals.  The timer is the ONLY thing executing in my program, and the modification times I have listed measure the entirety of the timer's event function which contains only synchronous code.  This means (as far as I can tell) that the only thing that could be responsible for the delay between timer events is screen rendering.

All my objects are tightly clustered.  Would screen rendering really take four times as long for 1000 objects as 500?  There is no opacity, and the only properties being edited are *x* and *y* values.

Specifically, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to re-render content than changing the positions and then calling event.updateAfterEvent().  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It depends, rendering and code execution are 2 different process each being able to slow down fps depending on what they have to do. For example if the rendering has to deal with graphics made of lot of vector shapes or very big bitmaps you'll reach the rendering limits pretty fast. As for code, loops, method calls, etc can become crippling when if you have too many object to deal with. You can easily know which one does what by setting the visible of your object to false which will leave the rendering out of the equation.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I set all the objects' visible properties to false to confirm, and sure enough it ran at 60 FPS with 1000 objects.  So are there any options for drawing on-the-fly other than vector shapes and bitmaps?

Comment: Also, what types of rendering processes are faster in general, without needing on-the-fly drawing capabilities?

Comment: ah once again I need to go with it depends. Of course you could give a try to Stage3D based frameworks or even better come up with your own but they have their drawbacks too (they need runtime preparation like loading to GPU etc which takes time). Stage3D might be the best answer for drawing at once 1000 or more object on screen. For classic display you need to experiment with bitmap only, vector only, then mix and try to find the right balance. Depending on matrix and vector complexity results can be very different.

Comment: From an animation perspective, you shouldn't need 1000 anythings.  What is there a 1000 of that need frame by frame code?  Look at what your 1000 things do and create an animation out of it.  For example, you make 1000 bees that are all their own instance with their own code updating every tic OR you look at them and see a swarm and create one swarm animation.

Comment: animation or video are static solutions meant for static needs. I don't think the PO is looking for static displaying.

Comment: If the bitmaps are all with small size,you may draw all bitmap to one bitmapdata, it may speed up. If they are not small, try stage3d.